# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') error when data fetching

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, fetch-api, react-component

I have `companies.json` and I am trying to fetch data from it and then display the company names as a checkbox, so here is my parent component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SimpleBox from "../components/sub-components/SimpleBox";
import BoxWithSearch from "../components/sub-components/BoxWithSearch";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";
import { listCompanies } from "../actions/companyActions";

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const companyList = useSelector((state) => state.companyList);
  const {  companies } = companyList;


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listCompanies());
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h3 className="title">Brands</h3>
          {companies.map((company) => (
            <BoxWithSearch type={"companies"} company={company} />
          ))}
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After BoxWithSearch component:

```
import React from "react";
import CheckBox from "../custom-components/CheckBox";

export default function BoxWithSearch(props) {
  return (
    <div className="search-w-box card">
      <div className="card-header">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder={`Search ${props.type}`} aria-label="Recipient's username"></input>
      </div>
      <div className="card-body">
          <CheckBox text={props.name} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here it goes to the checkbox:

```
import React from "react";

export default function CheckBox(props) {
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleCheck = (e) => {
    setChecked(e.target.checked || !isChecked);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <label className="checkbox-container">
        {props.text}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={(e) => toggleCheck(e)}
          id={props.id}
        />
        <span className="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </>
  );
}
```

But unfortunately, I am getting:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') error and I have no idea why and it is getting me crazy.`

Could you please have a look? And my JSON array is like this:

```
[
  {
    "slug": "Dickens-Franecki",
    "name": "Dickens - Franecki",
    "address": "12158 Randall Port",
    "city": "East Maureenbury",
    "state": "NE",
    "zip": "74529",
    "account": 31010023,
    "contact": "Lonzo Stracke"
  },
  {
    "slug": "Weissnat-Schowalter-and-Koelpin",
    "name": "Weissnat, Schowalter and Koelpin",
    "address": "92027 Murphy Cove",
    "city": "Port Malachi",
    "state": "WY",
    "zip": "56670-0684",
    "account": 81813543,
    "contact": "Kathryne Ernser"
  },
]
```

Comment: Use optional changing `companies?.map`.

Comment: What is optional changing? @Asifvora

Comment: Depends on your state configuration, before the listCompanies action to be finish, the companies can be undefined. That causes your companies.map can not be called. To fixit just replace companies.map by (companies || []).map.

Comment: Can you show your reducer?. Ideally i would set a initial in companyList reducer to be something like this. ```const INITIAL_STATE = { companies:[] }``` this will solve your problem. Because when the application mounts then for some time there is no companies property so you need to have an initial state

Comment: The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 3):

You can use Optional chaining (?.) to check you have data or not in the array.

Here you can check `what is optional-chaining?` and `how it works`.
[optional-chaining](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining)

```
{companies?.map((company) => (
  <BoxWithSearch 
    key={company.slug}
    type={"companies"} 
    company={company}
  />
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, check your array's (companies) value. there are no records so it shows the error,
second, if the data is fetched successfully and then it shows this undefined error,
you have to do:

```
{companies && companies.map((company) => (
        <BoxWithSearch type={"companies"} company={company} />
      ))}
```

by doing this you simply mean if there is data available in companies then add map()